# Convert date to month year format and pass it in the query

Tags: sql, db2, birt

I have a BIRT report where user will be entering the dates in dd-mm-yyyy format however I need to convert dd-mm-yyyy to MON-YYYY format.

I have tried to use VARCHAR_FORMAT(FIELDNAME,'MON-YYYY') however it doesn't work.

```
select …….
where VARCHAR_FORMAT(fieldname,'MON-YYYY') = '2017-05-15';
```

User would end the date as 
`15/05/2017`
The value present in the database for this field is `2017-05-15 07:30:00.0`

Comment: What is the actual type of `fieldname`?  Text (and if so, what format)?  `TIMESTAMP`?  Something else?  The usual way to do this kind of query is to use a range based on the input time; eg: `SELECT .... WHERE fieldName >= :inputDate - (DAYS(:inputDate) - 1) DAYS AND fieldName < :inputDate - (DAYS(:inputDate) - 1) DAYS + 1 MONTH`, or through the use of a calendar file.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse the field has data type DATETIME. I'm using date range however not sure how to convert the input date to MON-YYYY format.

Comment: @max092012 Please, provide a few sample `timestamp` (it’s equivalent to the `datetime` data type in Db2) values in your `fieldname` column, exact user’s input, and the result desired.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I have updated the question with your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from table (values
timestamp('2017-05-15-07.30.00')
) t(fieldname)
where
fieldname between to_date('15/05/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date('15/05/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 1 day
--date(fieldname) = to_date('15/05/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
;
```

You may run it as is.
Both cases work, but to use the 2-nd one efficiently, you must create an index by the `date(fieldname)` expression (since db2 10.5) or add `generated always` column to the table with the same expression and index on it.

Answer (score 1):

**update**

Apparently the column is not a string but a datetime which means the conversion is only

```
to_date(fieldname, 'MON-YYYY')
```

But if the column is used in a Where clause it shouldn’t be converted at all.

——

Use to_date and to_char to first convert your string to a date and then back to a string with the right format

```
 to_char(to_date(fieldname, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'MON-YYYY')
```

Comment: my field has date and time hence I tried SELECT  to_char(to_date(fieldname, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'MON-YYYY')  from table where fieldname  ='2017-05-15' however its not returning any row.

Comment: using like gives error as  SQLERRMC=2017-05-15-07.30.00.000000

Comment: This is going to ignore any indices on the table, because the functions will make the query non-SARGable.  `LIKE` will not improve the situation any.